# How can I recognize the vertical empty spaces in my markup in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

in this HTML file, there are a couple of divs that are absolute

I want to write a code in JavaScript that can tell me the row of each div.
Whenever in vertical axes we are no box there is a row, for me problem is how can I tell my application "there is a row"!

here my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            width    : 1170px;
            margin   : 0 auto;
            position : relative;
        }

        .box {
            position   : absolute;
            background : red;
            width      : 300px;
            height     : 300px;
            color      : #fff;
            font-size  : 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box" style="top: 20px; left: 30px" id="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box" style="height:100px; top: 90px; left: 530px" id="box2">box2</div>
    <div class="box" style="top: 1450px; left: 230px" id="box3">box3</div>
    <div class="box" style="top: 550px; left: 630px" id="box4">box4</div>
    <div class="box" style="top: 950px; left: 130px" id="box5">box5</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

I want my code to work with more or fewer boxes so I think I should write a function but without understanding these rows I can't do that...
Any advice?

Comment: You should start by formally defining what a `row` is - then you will be able to check which "row" any given DIV resides in.

Comment: Yes but this is my exact problem. I don't know which way is better to define a row for this application. should I say any vertical free space between these boxes is rows or another way? Even if this is the best approach I haven't found the best way to do that :')

Comment: How about defining some rows that start at the first box upper border and ending at it's bottom border, get those heights and that is your first row and consider that all other boxes that have their top border inside that row are on that row, than get the top border of the next box that is under first row and create your second row.. and so on

Comment: Well, problem definitions are usually purely mathematical issue - so it does not matter whether you're are beginner in programming, as long as you're good in math stuff. You can start on paper, with a Decart coordinate system and try to express your logic as one or more math equations.

Comment: @Gabriel Oh! this solution is interesting for me and I think it looks easier than my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example, first it find the rows min and max heights and then loops through all boxes and if the top border height is between a row top and
bottom height it assigns that box to that row, and you will get an object with your boxes ids and the rows they are in: (rows numbers starts at 0, i used the array position to get it, but you can assign any number you want when creating the rows array ) here is a sample output:

```
[
  {
    "box": "box1",
    "row": 0
  },
  {
    "box": "box2",
    "row": 0
  },
  {
    "box": "box3",
    "row": 3
  },
  {
    "box": "box4",
    "row": 1
  },
  {
    "box": "box5",
    "row": 2
  }
]
```

```js
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
// construct an array with the rows
function getRow(fromHeight) {
  const o = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    const boxRect = boxes[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if ((!o.top || o.top > boxRect.top) && boxRect.top > fromHeight) {
      o.top = boxRect.top;
      o.bottom = boxRect.bottom;
    }
  }
  return o;
}
let rows = [];
let fromHeight = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  let row = getRow(fromHeight);
  if (Object.keys(row).length !== 0) rows.push(row);
  fromHeight = row.bottom;
}
// console.log(rows);

// get array with every box row
let array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  const boxRect = boxes[i].getBoundingClientRect();
  var row = rows.findIndex(p => p.top <= boxRect.top && p.bottom >= boxRect.top);
  array.push({box:boxes[i].id, row: row});
}
console.log(array);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      width: 1170px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
    }

    .box {
      position: absolute;
      background: red;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box" style="top: 20px; left: 30px" id="box1">box1</div>
    <div class="box" style="height:100px; top: 90px; left: 530px" id="box2">box2</div>
    <div class="box" style="top: 1450px; left: 230px" id="box3">box3</div>
    <div class="box" style="top: 550px; left: 630px" id="box4">box4</div>
    <div class="box" style="top: 950px; left: 130px" id="box5">box5</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was the best solution and easy to understand.